# Does the razor support in ServiceStack depend on the MVC library?

Tags: servicestack

I was looking at the razor rockstars example to check out the razor functionality in ServiceStack and found that there was no mention of relying on the System.Web.Mvc libraries. The example project does not also have it as a reference. But taking a closer look at the web.config file in the exmaple, i found that under the "system.web.webpages.razor" section, the host factoryType being used is "System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory". Does this mean that the razor support in servicestack does depend on the MVC library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[ServiceStack.Razor](http://razor.servicestack.net/) does not require a dependency on MVC.

The `system.web.webpages.razor` section is to keep VS.NET intelli-sense happy and so you can use the same configuration found in MVC to configure Razor support in ServiceStack, which can also be done in code by adding any view namespaces to `Config.RazorNamespaces`.